# What happens when the last remaining players refuse to kill each other?

Tags: apex-legends

On the occasions that I survived until the end, the safe zone still had a radius of 30+ meters, so I never experienced what would happen after that. Is the safe zone reduced to zero radius and everyone starts taking damage? Is there a draw?

What would happen if the last remaining players would just stand next to each other and not fight?

Comment: Then you get two sequels...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, the ring will close completely and deal damage to players until a team is dead. You seem to take about 10 damage per tick rate of about 1.5 seconds.

There are plenty of examples on YouTube if you search along the lines of "apex legends heal off". I picked [this example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVjrzxAYGzs) because it's short and has no other unnecessary commentary, just to show you it is completely closed and the damage rate.

Comment: So what happens if both players have the same amount of health?

Comment: @noClue It's probably something lame like one of them having it happen one tick before; or the game just picking the first person on a list to die first or something.  I get the feeling it would be an extreme technical challenge, if even possible within the games coding, to test that.

Answer (score 5):

You will take about 10 damage per tick rate of about 1.5 seconds aa the answer above said.

However, it will be beyond unlikely that you will both die at the same time (if you have the same health).The ring will hit one player before another, this could be by 0.01 seconds. The one who goes in the storm first, even by such a gap, will die first.

Lets say the players both have same health and somehow both hit the ring at the exact same time, it will be likely that the winner will be chosen randomly.